# Varchar scalar function, returns truncated in SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I observed this weird behavior on SQL Server 2019.

This is the query which works fine in SQL Server 2017, but returns truncated text in SQL Server 2019.

Result on SQL Server 2017:

[image]

Result on SQL Server 2019:

[image]

SQL:

```
create or alter function dbo.testScalarFunction
(
    @id int
)
returns varchar(10)    as 
begin
    if(@id = 0)
        return 'zero'
    if(@id = 1)
        return 'one'
    if(@id = 2)
        return 'two'
    if(@id = 3)
        return 'three'
    if(@id = 4)
        return 'four'
    if(@id = 5)
        return 'five'
    if(@id = 6)
        return 'six'

    return 'null'
end
go

declare @intValue table
(
    id int identity(1,1)
    ,val varchar(10)
)

insert into @intValue(val) values ('A')
insert into @intValue(val) values ('B')
insert into @intValue(val) values ('C')
insert into @intValue(val) values ('D')
insert into @intValue(val) values ('E')
insert into @intValue(val) values ('F')
insert into @intValue(val) values ('G')
insert into @intValue(val) values ('H')

select *, dbo.testScalarFunction(id) testScalarFunction
from @intValue
```

Comment: Please do not show structure and data in pictures.

Comment: I can't replicate your problem [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=691e1b19c9143e419a1cb15ff183e94f). What build of 2019 are you running?

Comment: They *aren't* @KhoaHoàng ... They are showing you the results. They have posted full DML and DDL in the question if you look directly below that image...

Comment: @Larnu yeah , sorry

Comment: @Larnu my Sql Server 2019 build is  17134. Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM) - 15.0.2000.5 (X64)   Sep 24 2019 13:48:23   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Enterprise 10.0 <X64> (Build 17134: )

Comment: That's the release version, I suggest you update; there have been many bug fixes to 2019 in the last 2 years including to inlining of scalar functions, as well as several security fixes. Then I suggest you review your update processes as they clearly aren't working.

Comment: As per the question guide, please DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: @DaleK Again, the OP hasn't... There is a full DDL and DML script after those images... The OP is showing the varying results they have between versions; most likely due to not installing any updates in almost 2 years...

Comment: Your script works in the latest CU (KB5001090) of Sql Server. You need to update your installation.

Comment: @Larnu results count as data in my book... the guide doesn't specify just sample starting data, it just says data, and further clarifies with the second sentence (which I don't need to reproduce as its a couple of comments above).

Comment: Basically the same (fixed) issue as https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/269289/3690

Comment: Issue is resolved after updating Sql Server 2019. Thanks @Larnu

Comment: Now just sort out your update policy, @AmitKumar . Almost 2 years with no patching is a problem.